# Example of persistent with backend-specific operator

Tags: haskell, yesod

I would like to do a LIKE query in persistent, I'm using sqlite. The yesod book gives an example of using raw SQL to do it, but says:

> you can express a LIKE operator directly in the normal syntax due to a
>   feature added in Persistent 0.6, which allows backend-specific
>   operators

I couldn't find an example of that, though. Would somebody have an example of what it would mean to use a specific operator like LIKE with `selectList` or something equivalent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know I've used it before, but I can't remember where. Anyway, a simple example (not GHC-checked, apologies) would be:

```
selectList [Filter PersonName (Left $ PersistText "%Michael%") (BackendSpecificFilter "ILIKE")] []
```

Obviously you can create some helper function, e.g.:

```
icontains field val = Filter field (Left $ PersistText $ T.concat ["%", val, "%"]) (BackendSpecificFilter "ILIKE")
selectList [Personname `icontains` "Michael"] []
```

Comment: Thanks. The code does not compile, as you feared, but you were not far: Filter field (Left $ T.concat ["%", val, "%"]) (Filter seems to take a Either Text and not Either PersistText)

Comment: Neither of these worked for me, here's what did: `like field val = Filter field (Left $ T.concat ["%", val, "%"]) (BackendSpecificFilter "like")`

Comment: Future readers who want the easiest way to do `ILIKE` in Haskell and PostgreSQL, use [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.5.3/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html#v:ilike).

Comment: Where is this T.concat from?

Comment: `Data.Text` from the `text` package.

Comment: This is what worked for me: 
```icontains :: EntityField r T.Text -> T.Text -> Filter r```

```icontains field val = Filter field (FilterValue $ T.concat ["%", val, "%"]) (BackendSpecificFilter "ilike")```