# Select like in Yesod web framework's persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod

What is the best way to process `SELECT` query to `PostgreSQL` with the `LIKE` expression? I want to ask something like `selectList [EntityField .like. "abc%"] []`. I use Yesod's persistent and need to get my model, not another data type.

Comment: You can try something with the BackendSpecificFilter. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048143/example-of-persistent-with-backend-specific-operator